# Sublime text2: Replace with a sequence

Tags: sublimetext2

I have this:

```
    private void radioButton34_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (radioButton.Checked == true)
        { //blah}
    }

    private void radioButton35_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (radioButton.Checked == true)
        { //blah}
    }
```

but they are 100 buttons (no joke)
I wanna replace 'radioButton.Checked' with 'radioButtonX.Checked' in the sequence, for every 
radioButton.Checked that he finds, where X starts in 34, and ends in 100

Is it possible?
What if i want X to start in 20 or a anyother number? (noob here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ 1-Step solution
Hit replace (<kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (I guess) or `Find→Replace...`).
Search for `(?<=radioButton)(\d+)(_CheckedChanged(?:\n|.)*?radioButton)` with RegEx (`.*`) activated. (see below for explanation on the regex)
And replace with: `\1\2\1`
RegEx:

- `(?<=radioButton)`: the string start with radioButton
- `(\d+)`: it is followed by a bunch of numbers, we store this in \1
- `(_CheckedChanged(?:\n|.)*?radioButton)`: it is itself followed by _CheckedChange, any number of characters and newLine characters, and radioButton, this is stored in \2
- replace everything with \1\2\1, which means: keep the numbers, what's after that, and put again the numbers

2/ 2-Step Solution
A little more general solution (not limited to a 2-digit number).
Launch a search: (<kbd>⌘F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> or `Find→Find...`). Make sure the Regex box is selected on the left (`.*`).

Search for: `(?<=radioButton)\d+(?=_CheckedChanged)`

- `(?<=radioButton)`: radioButton should be in front of what you search
- `\d+` is any digit, but at least one
- `(?=_CheckedChanged)`: the number has to be followed by _CheckedChanged

Search for all these. Copy the results. Move all your cursors to the desired location, and paste.

If you have any question :-)

PS:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may be a stupid response, but off the top of my head, it should work if _CheckedChanged isn't used anywhere else.

1. Find all "_CheckedChanged("
2. Use your left arrow key to go to the end of X (notice multiple cursors)
3. Hold shift and hit the left arrow key twice to select X
4. Copy, then using your arrow keys move to radioButton.Checked and hit paste

I just realised you said 100. Obviously the above idea would only work if X is the same number of digits. You'll have to correct the 100th after.

There is surely a better way, but that should do the job I guess. 100 radio buttons!?

Comment: how do you set multiple cursors? win7 Edit: choose all of _CheckedChanged( on one of the lines and press alt+f3, then use keyboard to replace in multi lines :)

Comment: Also, i'm creating an application that employs the structural european norms, 100 buttons are for the density of various materials to determine their weight and effect on pavements (it uses everything since steel, cement, apples, and dry chicken poop (true story))